# Python. IF condition using Lambda function in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/eurusd_dukascopy.csv')
df.columns = ['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
df['oc'] = df.close - df.open

df['uptail'] = df['oc'].apply(lambda x: (df.high - df.close) if x >= 0 else (df.high - df.open))
```

Gives an error: *ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2963, placement implies 1*

I just want to do the following: if *df.oc* is a positive number, then d*f.uptail = (df.high - df.close)* ...else *df.uptail = (df.high - df.open)*

How can I crank this out?

Comment: Your lambda doesn't make use of it's parameter...

Comment: I tried on a phone but got lost in the logic. You probably want `np.where` but it's not clear exactly how it works for your example.

Answer (score 1):

[np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is more suited here.

```
df['uptail'] = np.where(df.close-df.open>=0, df.high-df.close, df.high-df.open)
```

Comment: For brevity: `df.close >= df.open` equals `df.close - df.open >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want `uptail` to be `close - open` if that's positive, and `high - open` if `close - open` is negative or 0.

You can achieve that with the following code:

```
df['uptail'] = df.high - df.open
df.loc[df.close > df.open, 'uptail'] = \
    df.loc[df.close > df.open, 'high'] - df.loc[df.close > df.open, 'close']
```